# is there a way to use ganache with dapps

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development, ethers.js, ganache, ganache-cli

For development I use Ganache and forking the mainnet. I also have a metamask wallet than can access this. The issue is that every-time I want to do something on a contract (like aave, uniswap etc) I need to write some code (ethersjs or web3). Is there a way I can connect a webapp (dapp) to my localhost ganache?

Comment: I think the frontend of aave and uniswap are open source, and anyone can change them and start them locally

Comment: @MajdTL I was hoping for something that might work for any dapp, to be a simple browser override

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Ganache usually runs on port `http://localhost:8545` (need to check your ganache configuration to make sure). Just need to create a provider that connect to it. For example with ethers.js you will do it this way:

`const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(“http://localhost:8545”)`

Comment: I was hoping for something that might work for any dapp, to be a simple browser override. This will require to checkout the dapp and run it. You code is exactly what I need to inject into a running app